# Find the equation of the line perpenducular to the plane $x-y+z = 4$

Tags: geometry

In geometry i am having difficulties in understanding how to find the equations.. e.g given

$$x-y+z =4 $$which passes through the point $(2,1,5)$ when asked to find the equation of the line perpendicular to the plane.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is $x-y+z$?

Comment: Any line $\frac{x-x_0}{1}=\frac{y-y_0}{-1}=\frac{z-z_0}{1}$ will be perpendicular to the plane, because $(1,-1,1)$ is the plane normal vector (i.e. perpendicular to the plane) and will be the line direction vector also.

Comment: The plane described by $x-y+z=4$ doesn't pass through the point $(2,1,5)$ though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property of being perpendicular (perpendicularity) is the relationship between two lines which meet at a right angle (90 degrees).

so try if $$x-y + z = 4; $$

then 
$$<x,y,z>$$

= $$<2,1,5> + t <1,-1,1>$$

which equals to

$$ <2+t , 1-t, 5+t>$$

Answer (score 0):

In general the plane: $\color{blue}{ax+by+cz+d=0}$ has a normal vector having its direction ratios $a$, $b$, & $c$.

The equation of the line having direction ratios $a$, $b$ & $c$ & passing through the point $(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1})$ is given by the general equation 
$$\color{red}{\frac{x-x_{1}}{a}=\frac{y-y_{1}}{b}=\frac{z-z_{1}}{c}=t} $$

Hence, the line perpendicular (i.e. parallel to the normal vector) to the given plane: $x-y+z=4$ has its direction ratios $a=1$, $b=-1$ & $c=1$ & passes through the given point $(2, 1, 5)$. Its equation is given as follows $$\frac{x-2}{1}=\frac{y-1}{-1}=\frac{z-5}{1}=t $$
$$\implies \color{green}{<2+t, 1-t, 5+t>} $$